# #VALUE Error using AVERAGEIFS; Error on range starting at > 0

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have data binned by two criteria starting at B2, with headers in B1 -> BV1 and A2 -> A101.

Cell A1 contains a tag for the data; "MYDATA".

Cells B1 -> BV1 are factors of 6: 0, 6, 12, 18...354. These are bin starts such that 0 represents data where 0 <= data < 6.
Cells A2 -> A101 are factors of 0.25: 0.25, 0.50, 0.75...49.75. These are mid bin values such that 0.25 represents data where 0.00 <= data < 0.50.

Here is a snapshot:

```
MYDATA  0       6       12      18
0.25    0.014   0.013   0.011   0.010
0.75    0.135   0.122   0.120   0.120
1.25    0.451   0.434   0.442   0.442
```

I wish to rebin this data into fewer bins, inherently averaging it when I do so.

I wish to rebin the rows by integer as 0 -> 1, 1 -> 2 etc up to 30 (data above 30 in original to be excluded). Starting at B6 = 0 (then B7 = 1 down to B36 = 30)
&
Rebin the columns by values of 30, so 0, 30...330. Starting at C5 = 0, then D5 = 30 up to N5 = 330.

I am attempting to do this with AVERAGEIFS using the following formula entered into cell C6 (columns and rows locked with $ ready to drag to form complete table):

```
AVERAGEIFS('DATA'!$A$1:$BI$101,'DATA'!$B$1:$BI$1,">"&C$5,'DATA'!$B$1:$BI$1,"<="&D$5,'DATA'!$A$2:$A$101,">"&$B6,'DATA'!$A$2:$A$101,"<"&$B7)
```

This is returning #VALUE error. In attempting to solve this I've used the "Evaluate Formula" option in Formulas -> Evaluate Formula -> Evaluate.
This highlights my first criterion, >C5 (written as ">"&C5) and upon hitting "Evaluate" changes this to ">"&0.

Looking at my data it is pulling the correct value for C5; 0. However I don't understand why this is returning #VALUE error. My understanding is that this is the first criteria defining the start of the range of columns selected from MYDATA. The end of the range of columns is then given by D5 (= 30).

What is the error in my understanding or my approach?

Comment: It is not at all clear what you're trying to do.  AND there are some technical issues - for example, the average range in your formula overlaps the area where the new table is going to be.  I'm going to assume that 1. In your first bin (upper left cell of the new data array) you want the average of all the old data that is >= 0 and < 1.  2. The last cell in the first column will have the average of all the old data that is >= 29 and < 30. 3. The first cell in the second column will have the average of all the old data that is >= 30 and < 31.  If that is not correct, please EDIT your answer...

Comment: ... to *clearly* explain your problem.  Also see the attempted solution below.

Comment: On second thought, I'm not going to attempt an answer because there are so many mistakes in your question.
1.  The data in row 2 of your table should be between 0.5 and 1.0.  It isn't.
2.  The data in row 3 of your table should be between 1.0 and 1.5.  It isn't.
3.  The second column starts with 6, so the fractional bins in column A
      should only go to 5.75, not 49.75.
If you expect anyone to help you with your problem, please EDIT your question and clearly explain your issues, using sample data that is not invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have criteria in columns and rows. For that type of setup you can't use `AVERAGEIFS`, but you can use an "array formula" like this:

`=AVERAGE(IF('DATA'!$B$1:$BI$1>C$5,IF('DATA'!$B$1:$BI$1<=D$5,IF('DATA'!$A$2:$A$101>$B6,IF('DATA'!$A$2:$A$101<$B7,'DATA'!$B$2:$BI$101)))))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Note 1: the range to average is at the end.
Note 2: perhaps you need `<=$B7` otherwise you'll miss some values